# In how many ways can you write down all 29 letters of the alphabet so that none of the "words" GLAD, HÄST, PONKE appear in the text string?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Before I ask the question, I am working with an alphabet that also includes the three letters **Å**, **Ä**, **Ö** which are from the Swedish alphabet. Therefore I am working with 29 letters instead of 26 which there are in the regular English alphabet.

**The question:**

In how many ways can you write down all 29 letters of the alphabet so that none of the "words" **GLAD**, **HÄST**, **PONKE** appear in the text string?

---

I am thinking about if I can use the **Inclusion–exclusion principle** to solve this problem, but can not figure out how I would use it.

Comment: Well, I would first calculate how many strings there are that contain GLAD. Let that set of strings be $E_1$. Then the same for HAST$\rightarrow E_2$; PONKE$\rightarrow E_3$. Then I would calculate the number of strings that contain exactly one of GLAD, HAST or PONKE, and call that number $S_1$. Then I would calculate how many have exactly two of those. Obviously $E_1 \cap E_2 = \emptyset$ ...

Comment: Note: GLAD = glad, HÄST = horse, PONKE = little boy.

Comment: @MattiP. Why should $E_1\cap E_2=\varnothing$? The sets $\{\rm G,\rm L,\rm A,\rm D\}$ and $\{\rm H,\rm Ä,\rm S,\rm T\}$ are disjoint! (it's not "HAST")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather conveniently, the three target words share no letters between them, so the number of strings containing given target words may be computed by treating each included word as one letter. The number of strings containing GLAD is $26!$, for example, since there are $26$ objects to permute after composing the four-letter word, and there are $22!$ strings containing both GLAD and PONKE.

Then, by inclusion/exclusion, the desired answer is $29!$

- minus the strings containing one of the words: $-26!-26!-25!$
- plus the strings containing two: $+23!+22!+22!$
- minus the strings containing three: $-19!$

Comment: @Arthur no, it's not HAST, it's H**Ä**ST, and Ä is distinct from A in the Swedish alphabet.

Comment: Right, I just read the title, which had "hast". I need to stop doing that.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I am not entirely sure I understand the numbers you give in your examples, namely $26!$ and $22!$. I think I am having trouble understanding the trick of "treating each included word as one letter". Is it possible to clarify?

Comment: Out of $26$ positions you put the $25$ letters not in "GLAD" in $25$ of the positions and the word "GLAD" in the remaining position. There are $26!$ ways to do that, since you are just arranging $26$ things ($25$ letters and $1$ word).

Comment: @Christoph I don't understand why we have $26$ respectively $22$ positions in the first and second example he gives?

Comment: You could also first pick the $4$ consecutive out of $29$ positions where "GLAD" goes, theres $26$ ways to do that, then arrange the remaining $25$ letters: $26\cdot 25!=26!$. (Instead, Parcly just treated "GLAD" as one unit and arranged $26$ items ($25$ letters and $1$ word).)

Comment: @Christoph Case of string with both "GLAD" and "PONKE": This doesn't seem to work for "GLADPONKE" though, or am I doing it wrong? $4$ letters in "GLAD" and $5$ in "PONKE" $9$ letters in "GLADPONKE". I pick $9$ consecutive out of $29$ positions where "GLADPONKE" goes, we can do that in $21$ ways. This due to the fact that the last position where "GLADPONKE" can go on is the $21$st position. We then arrange the remaining 20 letters in 20! ways. So $21*20! = 21!$. But he got $22!$?

Comment: GLAD and PONKE don't have to be next to each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113743/discussion-between-noname123-and-christoph).